# Task Parallel Library consuming lots of space on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I am using –

```
Task task = new Task(delegate { GetRecordsForEmailReplies(headingList, partialEntity); });
task.Start();
```

> to run some heavy methods, but the problem is it’s consuming lots of
>   space of CPU on server some time IIS Work process increased above 60%
>   thats why server gets stuck.

Is there any solution to manage this problem, so please let me know? or any other option to run these heavy method without blocking the page load?

Comment: It is difficult to say something without knowing the surrounding code. Could you provide more info about how and then this method get called? Btw, the better way to start a task is to use `Task.Run(() => GetRecordsForEmailReplies(headingList, partialEntity))`.

Comment: You need, quite literally, millions of `Task`s to create noticeable CPU pressure. Whatever your problem is, it will *not* be with the TPL - it will be due to your proprietary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested means for creating a new `Task` or `Task<T>` is to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with **.NET 4.0** or `Task.Run` with **.NET 4.5**.  There is a detailed explanation from [Stephen Toub here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/06/13/10024153.aspx) on the topic.

He explains that it's more efficient:

> For example, we take a lot of care within TPL to make sure that when accessing tasks from multiple threads concurrently, the "right" thing happens.  A Task is only ever executed once, and that means we need to ensure that multiple calls to a task's Start method from multiple threads concurrently will only result in the task being scheduled once.

Again, use the `Task.Run` instead:

```
Task.Run(() => GetRecordsForEmailReplies(headingList, partialEntity));
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that that will actually have significant effect.

Comment: As I am new to use Task, I'm also concern if thousands of user will access the same functionality at a time will this be able to handle the app pools?